# Combine rows based on conditionals

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to combine two rows from a data frame based on two conditionals (values in columns). My data looks like this:

```
Id    Date          Hour  POL   SJC   ABA
15    01/01/2017       1  15     18   NA
16    01/01/2017       1  NA     NA   4
17    01/01/2017       2  78     56   NA
18    01/01/2017       2  NA     NA   16
```

For this case, the values stored in the *Date* and *Hour* should be used as conditionals, so where the day and hour matches in two rows should be combined preserving the existing value in each column. The following is the expected result:

```
Id    Date          Hour  POL   SJC   ABA
15    01/01/2017       1  15     18   4
16    01/01/2017       2  78     56   16
```

I tried by using the next example:

```
db <- aggregate(my_data[-(1:2)], by= my_data[c("Date", "Hour")], 
          function(x) unique(as.numeric(x)))
```

As you can see here I'm using the unique() function trying to keep the existing values, but it does not seem to be working properly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by sharing your input data with dput()

Comment: Could it be that the second `Id` in your expected result should be `17`?

Comment: I'll updated with dput() format. @Georgery yeah, that was my bad but the expected id result should be 17

Answer (score 2):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Date, Hour) %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.))))

  Date        Hour    Id   POL   SJC   ABA
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 01/01/2017     1    15    15    18     4
2 01/01/2017     2    17    78    56    16
```

Comment: I tried by using this approach but I faced a message error that I haven´t been able to go over it. It seems it's a basic error but I'm not getting it. 

See the error message below: 

```Error in across(everything(), ~first(na.omit(.))) : 
  could not find function "across"
```
I've updated dplyr() package as well, as well writing down the root of the function to avoid call a duplicate function ( dplyr::across) and nothing has worked so far.

Comment: That is strange. Do you have a `dplyr` version 1.0.0 or higher?

Comment: Currently, 0.8.5 Is the version a problem? It seems that it wasn't updated last time. I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, you need 1.0.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Your call of the function `aggregate` is almost correct. There was only a comma missing before the list of variables to aggregate by. The by-argument should be a list of vectors you want to aggregate by. Also, I would not use `unique(x)` as a function as it may return a vector if there are several valid values. If you use `max()` with `na.rm=T`, it works just fine.

```
> d.agg=aggregate(d[,-(1:2)],by=d[,c("Date","Hour")],FUN=max, na.rm=T)
> colnames(d.agg)[1]='Date'
> colnames(d.agg)[2]='Hour'

## Result:
> d.agg
        Date Hour POL SJC ABA
1 01/01/2017    1  15  18   4
2 01/01/2017    2  78  56  16
```

Comment: This worked properly. I'm not getting at all how the FUN=max argument works. Considering that for two rows there is only one value for each one of the three columns, that value could be considered as the highest number, that is why by using max argument it returns 1 value per column while it's been aggregated, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if there is a vector with NAs and only one numeric value, `max(x, na.rm=T)` will return the one value (as will `min()` or even `unique()`). But if there happen to me more than one numeric value, `max()` will only take the highest one. So, if one `NA` is improperly stored as `0`, it still works. If you are sure that you have only one value per date/hour, you may use whatever you want.